# how to build a grid list like this in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

[image]

1. this grid view has 2 rows
2. this grid always has 5 columns
3. this grid scrollable in X axis(horizontally)
4. this grid item is a custom view(has a image and some text)
5. this grid item is auto-fit

I'm new to swiftUI,I want to build a grid view as highlight image above, desire to be helped from you, thanks!

Comment: You can achieve this with a LazyHStack and a ScrollView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let numberOfColumn = 5
    let rows = [GridItem(.fixed(50)),GridItem(.fixed(50))]
    let space:Float = 10.0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHGrid(rows: rows ,spacing: 10, content: {
                    ForEach(0 ..< numberOfColumn * 2) { item in
                        Rectangle() //replace with your cell view 
                            .frame(width: CGFloat( getColumnWidth(width: Float(proxy.size.width))))
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getColumnWidth(width: Float) -> Float {
        ((width) - ((space)*Float(numberOfColumn-1))) / Float(numberOfColumn)
    }
}
```